# PHP echo mysql table column names for html table header

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

**RESOLVED**

Works perfectly! Here is my final code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
                echo "<th>";
                echo $col;
                echo "</th>";
            }
      ?>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
  // Write rows
  mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
    <tr>
      <?php         
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    ?>
      <td><button id="edit_project_button(<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>)" class="edit-project-button edit button" onclick="editproject(<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

I wish to echo out a HTML table using mysql_fetch functions appropriately. I plan on making a *thead* to contain the mysql table column names and a *tbody* to contain the mysql table resultset. The SQL query selects a couple of columns from the table, with default limit set.

**The issue:** It doesn't seem to print the first row of table data, everything else displays (record #1 missing)

It displays the  with column names echo'd within each , it then **skips** the first record and successfully echo's the 2nd row onward. For example:

```
| id | firstname | lastname | date_start | date_end   | clientid | members | edit          |
|  2 | Cal       | Clark    | 2012-12-12 | 2012-12-12 | 22       | Rob     | (edit button) |
|  3 | Rob       | Robin    | 2012-12-12 | 2012-12-12 | 33       | Cal     | (edit button) |
```

I'm 100% sure that the first record will display from my query in phpmyadmin.

Here is my code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
                echo "<th>";
                echo $col;
                echo "</th>";
            }

      ?>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php
  // Write rows
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[5]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>
    <td><button id="edit_project_button(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)" class="edit-project-button edit button" onclick="editproject(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I feel so oblivious right now =/

Comment: Not sure about the question at hand but you realize you're in a while loop there right you really don't have to explicitly call each row with $row[x], nor should you be since that would mean setting up your HTML without knowing how many records you're going to have at any given point. Either use an increment value or output the array to $row then do a foreach on that.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense and will revise that part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make a rewind of your data first!!

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
...
```